# Why C# supports structure when we have classes and interfaces for supporting OOP concepts

Tags: c#, class, oop, struct, interface

When we can achieve all the OOP concepts using classes and objects then why C# still support structures.

Comment: OOP has little to do with value vs. reference semantics. Instances of C# `structs` **are** still "objects", just always passed by-value instead of by-reference and have other limitations for practical reasons.

Comment: "Achieve all the OOP concepts" isn't the only thing you are trying to do when you write code...

Comment: Also, OOP itself needs to die (or at least stop _getting in the way_ of my expressiveness). Immutability and FP is the future :)

Comment: Can you please brief the Immutability and FP @Dai

Comment: @Dai sounds like you need to get into F#?